# Autocomplete in google apps script editor not always aware of type/context

Tags: google-apps-script, autocomplete, ide

I'm getting started with Google Apps scripting, and find the autocomplete very useful. However, once you are inside a new function, autocomplete doesn't seem to have any way of knowing what the type is for the parameter. I've seen some answers about python ideas that say that using javadoc will work. But I'm not able to figure it out. Any suggestions?

```
function myfunc1(){
  var activeSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  activeSheet//.autocomplete works here
  myfunc2(activeSheet)
}

function myfunc2(myActiveSheet){
  myActiveSheet//.autocomplete doesn't work here
}
```

Comment: Do a search in the [Apps Script Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list).  If you don't find something, you can make a feature request.  You might also want to check out the Google Apps Script group.  [Community - Apps Script](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: It doesn't necessarily answer your question, but one thing I stopped doing was putting full-stops/periods at the end of my comments as I found they confused the auto-complete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are limitations to what the UI can do in terms of autocomplete.

Usually I just keep the reference documentation open in another tab and refer to that, but you can also trick the UI into auto completing using comments:

```
function myfunc2(myActiveSheet){
  /*
      var myActiveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  */
  myActiveSheet //.autocomplete now works here
}
```

Comment: That's hilarious. And awesome. The answer related to a python IDE seemed to do something similar using the javadoc, in that it required you to explicitly tell the IDE what type it was so that autocomplete would work. It's too bad you can't do that with this UI.  Thanks so much for the answer.

Comment: Glad you like it :)  Sounds like with the Python IDE they implemented it that way on purpose, I'm pretty sure this Apps Script solution is just exploiting a bug, but it does the trick.

Comment: This is one of my Favourite Tricks! It's nice to know I'm not the only one doing this.

Comment: wow, that is fantastic ... thank you for sharing! it still works 5 years later...

Comment: The new editor uses JSDoc for the parameter types. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66381182/320036).

Answer (score 2):

The [new editor](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/releases#december_7_2020) uses [JSDoc](https://jsdoc.app/tags-param.html) for parameter types. So declare the parameter in the docs, and specify its type between the braces `{}`.

```
/**
 * @param {SpreadsheetApp.Sheet} sheet
 */
function myfunc(sheet) {
  sheet //.autocomplete now works here
}
```