# Autocomplete Not Working - Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm having trouble with the autocomplete feature in Google App Script.

Built-in methods like SpreadsheetApp. will provide an autocomplete menu with methods to choose from.

However, if I create my own child object, autocomplete works for a little while, and then it just stops working.

for example:

`var skywardRoster = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();`

skywardRoster. will produce method options for a while, and then it stops.

However, the code still functions, and methods work if I type them out manually, so I know the declarations must be right. The menu simply won't appear, and it's just very inconvenient to have to look up each method individually as I go.

I have tried: breaking the variable and retyping that line; copy and pasting the code back into the editor; using different browsers; copying the gs file itself and working within the copy; and signing out completely and signing back in. Nothing seems to get it back to work.

I'm really new to coding, and I'm not sure what can be causing this.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: I found something interesting that might help.

Had the same problem you describe. Autocomplete worked great, then later, it stopped.

Turns out, I had a comment with a period in it. Deleted the period and autocomplete started working again. Almost was like the script editor saw the period and began expecting something.

Comment: Maybe this is related to including a dot/period in a comment. Are you still having this issue? Do you usually add comments to your code including dots/periods?

Comment: Thanks! At some point it just stopped happening. Maybe google fixed it?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check [*Built-in Google Services:Using autocomplete*](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/):

> The script editor provides a "content assist" feature, more commonly called "autocomplete," which reveals the global objects as well as methods and enums that are valid in the script's current context. To show autocomplete suggestions, select the menu item *Edit > Content assist* or press *Ctrl+Space*. Autocomplete suggestions also appear automatically whenever you type a period after a global object, enum, or method call that returns an Apps Script class. For example:
>
> - If you click on a blank line in the script editor and activate autocomplete, you will see a list of the global objects.
> - If you type the full name of a global object or select one from autocomplete, then type `.` (a period), you will see all methods and enums for that class.
> - If you type a few characters and activate autocomplete, you will see all valid suggestions that begin with those characters.

Comment: I tried this. It works great for built-in global objects, and objects that I declare today. But none of my the objects that I declared a few days ago will display methods.

Comment: For example: `var test = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();` In this case, test should contain all the built in methods for sheets. When I create test, the autocomplete option works great. A few days later, it just stopped working. Even by manually clicking in the edit menu, the methods will not display.

Answer (score 2):

Since this was the first result on google for a non-working google script autocompletion, I will post my solution here as it maybe helps someone in the future.

The autocompletion stopped working for me when I assigned a value to a variable for a second time.

Example:

```
var cell = tableRow.appendTableCell();
...
cell = tableRow.appendTableCell();
```

So maybe create a new variable for the second assignment just during the implementation so that autocompletion works correctly. When you are done with the implementation you can replace it with the original variable.

Example:

```
var cell = tableRow.appendTableCell();
...
var replaceMeCell = tableRow.appendTableCell(); // new variable during the implementation
```

And when the implementation is done:

```
var cell = tableRow.appendTableCell();
...
cell = tableRow.appendTableCell(); // replace the newly created variable with the original one when you are done
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a way how to improve Google Apps Script development experience. Sometimes autocomplete misses context. For example for Google Spreadsheet trigger event parameters. I solved the problem by using clasp and @ts-check.

clasp allows to edit sources in VS Code on local machine. It can pull and push Google Apps Script code. [Here is an article how to try it.](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/04/01/working-with-google-apps-script-in-visual-studio-code-using-clasp/)

When you move to VS Code and setup environment you can add //@ts-check in the beginning of the JavaScript file to help autocomplete with the special instructions. [Here is the instructions set.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-checking-javascript-files.html)

My trigger example looks like this (notice autocompletion works only in VS Code, Google Apps Script cloud editor doesn't understand @ts-check instruction):

```
//@ts-check

/**
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnEdit} e
 */
function onEditTrigger(e) {
    var spreadsheet = e.source;
    var activeSheet = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet();
    Logger.log(e.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree, Google Script's autocomplete feature is pretty poor comparing with most of other implementations. However the lack is uderstandable in most cases and sometimes the function can be preserved.

### Loosing context

The autocomplete is limited to Google objects (Spreasheets, Files, etc.). When working with them you get autocomplete hints, unless you pass such object instance to function as an argument. The context is lost then and the editor will not give you suggestions inside the called function. That is because js doesn't have type control.

You can pass an id into the function instead of the object (not File instance but fileId) and get the instance inside of the function but in most cases such operation will slow the script.

### Better solution by Cameron Roberts

Cameron Roberts came with something what could be [Goole's intence or a kind of hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378678/autocomplete-in-google-apps-script-editor-not-always-aware-of-type-context), don't know. At the beginning of a function assign an proper object instance to parameter wariable and comment it to block:

```
function logFileChange(sheet, fileId){
  /*
    sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  */
  sheet.appendRow([fileId]); // auto completion works here
}
```

[Auto completion preserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNunU.png)